# How did Naruto restore Kakashi's left eye?

Tags: naruto

In Naruto manga chapter 675, Uchiha Madara attacked Hatake Kakashi and stole his left eye. Soon after Madara left Uzumaki Naruto soon appeared and restored Kakashi's left eye. It's seems that Kakashi's new eye is not Sharingan.

Q: What did Naruto do exactly?

[image: Naruto shows up and helped Kakashi]

[image: Kakashi's new eye]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was thanks to Naruto's new power: [Ying Yang Release](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Yin%E2%80%93Yang_Release) that he was able to restore it. If you remember  [Hagoromo Ōtsutsuki](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Hagoromo_%C5%8Ctsutsuki)  transfer his powers to Naruto (and Sasuke). The answer comes from the Naruto Wikipedia:

> *After receiving power from Hagoromo, Naruto Uzumaki gained the ability to use Yin–Yang Release to stabilise life forces and restore missing organs through physical contact. However, there appears to be a limit to the extent to what this power can heal: While he was able to save Might Guy from the normally fatal consequences of unleashing all Eight Gates, he was unable to repair the damage done to his leg as a result of using Might Guy, and Guy spent the remainder of his life wheelchair-bound. Naruto was also able to resuscitate Obito after the Ten-Tails was extracted from him, but both were aware that his death was unavoidable when he was struck by Kaguya Ōtsutsuki's All-Killing Ash Bones.*